# Swift4. Dictionaries merging

Tags: swift, случайные-числа, словари, swift4

Возникла одна проблема. Есть два словаря с одинаковыми ключами. Мне необходимо соединить их таким образом чтобы получать значения пополам рандомным образом.

Comment: А в чем проблема то?

Comment: @Vitaly я просто новичок и не получается пока сделать это.

Answer (score 2):

Для объединения словарей в Swift имеется метод Dictionary  `merging(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`. Пример использования по Вашему вопросу:

```
let dict1 = ["a": "a", "b": "b", "c": "c", "d": "d"]
let dict2 = ["a": "A", "b": "B", "c": "C", "d": "D"]

let resultDict = dict1.merging(dict2, uniquingKeysWith: { Bool.random() ? $0 : $1 })
```

И результатом будет что-то вроде

```
["a": "A", "b": "b", "c": "c", "d": "D"] // Как повезет
```

Answer (score 0):

Можете что-то подобное попробывать:

```
dic2.forEach { key, value in
    if dic1[key] != nil {
        dic1[key] = arc4random_uniform(2) == 0 ? dic1[key] : dic2[key]
    }
    else {
        dic1[key] = value
    }
}
```

Проход делаем по дикшинари которое меньше. А мержим в дикшинари которое больше.

Comment: А если словари одинаковы по размеру?

Comment: @IgorMokritskyi Если словари одинаковые, то без разницы по какому делать проход и в какой добавлять новые элементы.